# Bluetooth Sharing permission change crash the app

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I am developing an app with *bluetooth-peripheral* capability in **Background modes**. This makes the app ask for permission for **Bluetooth Sharing**:

[image: Bluetooth Sharing permissions]

If the user initially does not allow the permission and then goes to change it, the app crashes unexplainably, a different varieties of stack traces, totally unrelated to the procedure. Is the app killed when the permission is changed, for sandboxing or whatever reasons?

Comment: The duplicate question is about permissions for Contacts but it's all the same as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @rmaddy I changed the question because that was my suspect but it didn't happen with location permissions so I was confused. Thanks for redirecting me to the right place. :)